# Duality Principle, but confused by the example

Tags: boolean-algebra, dual

The dual of a Boolean expression can be obtained by interchanging sums and products; also interchanging 0 and 1.
But the dual of  xy̅ + 1 is (x' + y) · 0  ( I think)

Or the dual is (x + y) · 0.

Q: do we need to change variable to its complement?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When taking the **dual** of \$(xy'+1)\$, you need to replace ANDs with ORs (also ORs with ANDs) and 1s with 0s or 0s with 1s. There is no need to take the complement of variables in the expression. The dual of the expression in your question will be \$(x+y') \cdot0\$

However, if you are trying to find the **complement** of \$(xy'+1)\$, then by DeMorgan's law, you will have to take the complements of variables also:
\$(xy'+1)' = (xy')'\cdot1' = (x'+y)\cdot0\$